# Removing com.apple.quarantine from files on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, file

From time to time a user uploads a file with a tag "com.apple.quarantine".    This is added, I think, when the user has downloaded a file onto his computer from the internet.

My question is, how do I remove this from a file if I'm on Linux?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "on Linux"? That's an OS X feature, not a Linux feature. Also see [How to remove xattr com.apple.quarantine from files with that extended attribute?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/87313/83961)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setfattr.  On linux the extended attribute should be in the "user." namespace (your mileage may vary):

```
setfattr -x 'user.com.apple.quarantine' file1 [ file2 [ ... ] ]
```

Unfortunately, the -xattr predicate hasn't made it into GNU find yet so processing a complete hierarchy involves a brute-force-and-ignorance approach looking something like this:

```
cd /path/to/search

errors=/var/tmp/setfattr.errors

find . -exec setfattr -x 'user.com.apple.quarantine' {} + 2> "$errors"
```

After which the $errors file should only contain entries for files which didn't have the relevant attribute:

```
grep -v 'No such attribute' -- "$errors"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
touch /tmp/com.apple.quarantine.test1
touch /tmp/com.apple.quarantine.test2
```

Then run following codes.

```
for f in $(find /tmp/ -type f|grep -i 'com.apple.quarantine');
do
        OLD_NAME=$(echo $f|awk -F "/" '{print $NF'})
        NEW_NAME=$(echo $OLD_NAME|sed "s/com\.apple\.quarantine\.//g")
        echo $NEW_NAME
        DIR_NAME=$(dirname $f)
        cd $DIR_NAME
        mv "$OLD_NAME" "$NEW_NAME"
done
```

Now there is only **test1** and **test2** at under the /tmp file.